# Failed to catch a chaincode event when the the first chaincode who set the event is invoked by a second chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to catch an event payload from a chaincode A deployed in my infra, when I tried to catch the event payload directly from the chaincode A, it works, but when I try to catch the same event payload when a chaincode A is invoked by another chaincode B, it doesn't work. Any help ?

Comment: I believe it's not possible for chaincode that is called by other chaincode to emit an event, I thought I had seen someone link in a reference to where this is documented but I can't find the link or the original discussion where I had seen this, sorry

Comment: Thank you for this quick response, but it would be very helpful, if we have the link of the original discussion

Comment: Sorry, I can't find it. There are many different channels for fabric discussion and if it was on rocket chat then that isn't a good place to try to search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest fabric documentation, the limitation is described that only the top level chaincode can call setEvent to register a chaincode event.
https://hlf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developapps/transactioncontext.html#stub

Comment: I also found the information here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/blob/main/shim/interfaces.go